# Android: редактирование контактов через REST-интерфейс

Tags: android, api, rest

Есть потребность синхронизировать контакты а телефоне с Android с офисной CRM.
Через Google делать это нет возможности.
Существуют ли программы, позволяющие создавать/редактировать/удалять контакты на телефоне через REST-API? 
Как я вижу это:
 1. На телефоне запущено некое приложение(служба), слушающее порт HTTP 8080. Телефон ( по wifi) находится в одной офисной сети с сервером CRM
 2. Скрипт на сервере периодически синхронизирует список контактов CRM с телефоном, запрашивая телефон по HTTP (например http://192.168.0.100/contact/add?number=111&name=vasya)

Скорее всего готового приложения нет, придётся писать самому, в связи с эти вопросы:
 1. Допускает ли система Android автоматическое создание телефонного контакта (без открытия своего приложения)?
 2. Нет ли ограничений на количество контактов в записной книжке телефона (сейчас в CRM порядка 10 тыс. номеров)?

Answer (score 1):

Да, готового приложения скорее всего нет.

1. Да, система Android допускает возможность создания контактов, только нужно будет заранее выдать вашему приложению разрешение на доступ к контактам
2. Ограничения на количество контактов в телефонной книге нет, только памятью устройства ограничено, но на 10 тыс. номеров места хватит в любом Android телефоне, как мне кажется